# WPF ComboBox - Vertical display with 45° rotated items

Tags: wpf, combobox, rotation

I want to use a ComboBox in WPF to store some names, but I want the combobox itself to be vertical, and when you click on it, it shall display every item with another 45° rotation so that it's more readable. Something like: l / / / /

I achieved some of it doing this:

```
                        <ComboBox Name="combo" 
                                  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <ComboBox.LayoutTransform>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
                            </ComboBox.LayoutTransform>
                            <ComboBox.Items>                                
                                <TextBox>
                                    <TextBox.LayoutTransform>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="315" />
                                    </TextBox.LayoutTransform>
                                </TextBox>
                            </ComboBox.Items>
                        </ComboBox>
```

I fill the combobox like this:

```
        m_Main.combo.Items.Clear();
        foreach (PlayerInfo player in m_CurrentData.PlayersInfo)
        {
            m_Main.comboPlayer1.Items.Add(player.Name);                    
        }
```

But only the first item gets rotated, plus i get a blank item on top of the actual items (I fill the combobox items at runtime).
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: no more blank item as i clear the items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works (if I correctly understood what you want)

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Grid>  
    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="100">
      <ComboBox.LayoutTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
      </ComboBox.LayoutTransform>
      <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" IsItemsHost="True">
            <StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
              <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
            </StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
          </StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
      <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
          <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
              <RotateTransform Angle="315" />
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Style>
      </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <ComboBoxItem>Hello</ComboBoxItem>
      <ComboBoxItem>World</ComboBoxItem>
      <ComboBoxItem>Foo</ComboBoxItem>
      <ComboBoxItem>Bar</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

[image]

Comment: Mmmh this is even better actually, I was gonna ask how to leave the combobox fully vertical, and only the subitems at 45°. Nice !

Answer (score 0):

You might need to override the combobox itemtemplate like this -

```
<ComboBox Name="combo"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ComboBox.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
        </ComboBox.LayoutTransform>
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}">
                <TextBox.LayoutTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="315" />
                </TextBox.LayoutTransform>
            </TextBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Can you paste your code where you are filling the textboxes at runtime? Looking at that might help..

Comment: I was assuming that you are setting comboPlayer1 as the itemsource for the combobox. And i agree with sixlettervariables that you wont be abe to edit the text in textbox as the source is immutable. But just to show up the text u need to set the text mode to oneway.

Comment: Yes! this is it. Only thing is the 315° angle should be set at 45° then it's perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `DataTemplate` and add a `Binding` to the `TextBox.Text` property. Now I'm assuming you want to edit the name because you are using a `TextBox`. As it stands your code will not support editing those strings, because they are immutable. So my answer makes the assumption you'd like to edit them:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="combo" 
          Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <ComboBox.Resources>         
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PlayerInfo}">
             <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}">
                 <TextBox.LayoutTransform>
                     <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
                 </TextBox.LayoutTransform>
             </TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

And your code behind should set the `ItemsSource` to `m_CurrentData.PlayersInfo`.

```
this.combo.ItemsSource = m_CurrentData.PlayersInfo;
```

Ideally this would be done through bindings in the XAML, but as this stands it will work. Be sure to set up the `xmlns:local` definition in your XAML so the `DataType` on the `DataTemplate` works.

Comment: Keep in mind to see reactive changes to your edits you'll need to make sure the `PlayerInfo` class inherits from `DependencyObject` or implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: It does not solve my problem, getting the combobox to stand vertically is done. The problem is to display the items at a 45° angle from the combobox, so that it's more readable.

Comment: Also, about the binding, I gave up a while ago on it. I just do the old school refresh. My data comes from PHP/CLR through Phalanger, it's stored in Dictionaries etc. And last but not least, the m_CurrentData object is destroyed before a new one is deserialized, so even if PlayersInfo did inherit from DependencyObject, it would never get the chance to notify anything, or am I wrong?